# SQL query not showing all results when running in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ssms

I am running the below code in SSMS and am getting 1,481 results.

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql =
STUFF(
(SELECT
NCHAR (10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +
N'SELECT
LEFT('+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N', LEN('+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N') - 12) AS Office,
pt_copysupp COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Supplier_Code,
suname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Supplier_Name,
pt_date as Tran_Date,
pt_trantype COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Tran_Type,
pt_header_ref COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Tran_Ref,
pt_gross as Local_Gross,
pt_currencycode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Foreign_Currency_Code,
pt_curr_valu As Foreign_Currency_Gross
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_transactions
inner Join ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_accounts on ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_transactions.pt_copysupp = ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_accounts.sucode
where pt_trantype in (''INV'', ''CRN'', ''PAY'')
and pt_date between ''1/1/2020'' and ''12/31/2020''
and su_country like ''%China%'''
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE NAME like '%AccountsLive'
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '');
exec(@Sql);
```

However, when putting this code into VBA to construct a wider used spreadsheet (see below), only 145 results show?

```
Sub supplier_country()
'run SQL based on supplier country

Dim Conn As Object
Dim recset As Object
Dim SQLQry As String
Dim sConnect As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim DataBaseSource As String
Dim ServerSource As String
Dim SCountry As String
Dim lrow As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set recset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
'if supplier name is empty go to next macro
If IsEmpty(Range("C11")) Then
    'go to next macro
    analysis_code
Else

'clear sheet contents
    ActiveSheet.Rows("17:1000000").Clear

'set parameters
    ServerSource = Sheets("Servers + Databases").Range("G27").Value                 'choose the server the database is located
    InvoiceTo = Format$(Sheets("Search").Range("C5").Value, "m/d/yyyy")             'choose the date the search starts from
    InvoiceFrom = Format$(Sheets("Search").Range("C6").Value, "m/d/yyyy")           'choose the date the search ends from
    SCountry = Range("C11").Value                                                   'choose supplier country to search by
    
'insert server name and database name
    sConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
               "Password=ExcelRep0rt;" & _
               "User ID=ExcelReport;" & _
               "Data Source=" & ServerSource & ";" & _
               "Use Encryption for Data=False"
    
    Conn.Open sConnect

'SQL query
    SQLQry = " SET NOCOUNT ON DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);" & _
                " SET @Sql =" & _
                " STUFF(" & _
                " (SELECT" & _
                " NCHAR (10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +" & _
                " N'SELECT" & _
                " LEFT('+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N', LEN('+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N') - 12) AS Office," & _
                " pt_copysupp COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Supplier_Code," & _
                " suname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Supplier_Name," & _
                " pt_date as Tran_Date," & _
                " pt_trantype COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Tran_Type," & _
                " pt_header_ref COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Tran_Ref," & _
                " pt_gross as Local_Gross," & _
                " pt_currencycode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as Foreign_Currency_Code," & _
                " pt_curr_valu As Foreign_Currency_Gross" & _
                " FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_transactions" & _
                " inner Join ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_accounts on ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_transactions.pt_copysupp = ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_accounts.sucode" & _
                " where pt_trantype in (''INV'', ''CRN'', ''PAY'')" & _
                " and pt_date between ''" & InvoiceTo & "'' and ''" & InvoiceFrom & "''" & _
                " and suname like ''%" & SCountry & "%'''" & _
                " FROM sys.databases d" & _
                " WHERE NAME like '%AccountsLive'" & _
                " FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)" & _
                " .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '');" & _
                " exec(@Sql);"
    
    Debug.Print SQLQry
    
'import table - choose range of where to put the table
    Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
        recset.Open SQLQry, Conn
        Range("C17").CopyFromRecordset recset
        recset.Close

    Conn.Close
    Set recset = Nothing

'remove any trailing spaces
        For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            V = c.Value
            If V <> "" Then
                If Not c.HasFormula Then
                    c.Value = Trim(V)
                End If
            End If
        Next c

'sort by supplier name
    lrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Search").Range("C18").Value) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Search").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Search").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E17:E" & lrow) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Search").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D17:D" & lrow) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Search").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F17:F" & lrow) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortTextAsNumbers
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Search").Sort
            .SetRange Range("C16:K" & lrow)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End If

'convert CRN to negative
    If IsEmpty(Range("C17")) Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        'local gross amount
            Range("M17").Formula = "=IF(G17=""CRN"",I17*-1,I17)"
            Range("M17").Copy Range("M17:M" & lrow)
            Range("M17:M" & lrow).Copy
            Range("I17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'foreign currency gross
            Range("M17").Formula = "=IF(G17=""CRN"",K17*-1,K17)"
            Range("M17").Copy Range("M17:M" & lrow)
            Range("M17:M" & lrow).Copy
            Range("K17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    
'convert PAY to negative
    If IsEmpty(Range("C17")) Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        'local gross amount
            Range("M17").Formula = "=IF(G17=""PAY"",I17*-1,I17)"
            Range("M17").Copy Range("M17:M" & lrow)
            Range("M17:M" & lrow).Copy
            Range("I17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'foreign currency gross
            Range("M17").Formula = "=IF(G17=""PAY"",K17*-1,K17)"
            Range("M17").Copy Range("M17:M" & lrow)
            Range("M17:M" & lrow).Copy
            Range("K17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Columns(13).ClearContents
    End If

'add GBP conversion
    If IsEmpty(Range("C17")) Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Range("L17").Formula = "=IF(K17=0,I17/ROUND(PALO.DATAC(""PaloACS/ManAcc"",""FXRates"",""Actual"",'Servers + Databases'!$B$35,'Servers + Databases'!$B$36,J17,""Average Rate"")/PALO.DATAC(""PaloACS/ManAcc"",""FXRates"",""Actual"",'Servers + Databases'!$B$35,'Servers + Databases'!$B$36,""GBP"",""Average Rate""),4),K17/ROUND(PALO.DATAC(""PaloACS/ManAcc"",""FXRates"",""Actual"",'Servers + Databases'!$B$35,'Servers + Databases'!$B$36,J17,""Average Rate"")/PALO.DATAC(""PaloACS/ManAcc"",""FXRates"",""Actual"",'Servers + Databases'!$B$35,'Servers + Databases'!$B$36,""GBP"",""Average Rate""),4))"
        Range("L17").Copy Range("L17:L" & lrow)
    End If

'format sheet
    'Number Format
        Range("I17:I1000000").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00)"
        Range("K17:L100000").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00)"
        Columns(8).NumberFormat = "0"
    'Align
        Range("F17:H1000000").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    'Autofit
        Columns(5).AutoFit

End If

    Range("C11").Select

End Sub
```

So you can see the same SQL query is within this VBA code...anyone have any ideas why the VBA isn't populating the query? (Sorry about the length of the VBA code, but thought it best to show the whole thing!)

Comment: Point #1 - when building a SELECT statement like that, you are potentially exposing your data to SQL injection (yes, while that's often referred to for websites running SQL statements, there's nothing stopping the same potential malicious activity occurring here).    Incorporating the SQL statement in a parameterised stored procedure would be a safer course of action.

Comment: Point #2 - we can only take your word that it's running the same SQL query, because you're incorporating values from cells as the parameters (as opposed to the hard-coded values that you've got in your first query, for the date-range and country, that you're running in SQL Mgmt Studio).  You have a debug line that outputs the "SQLQry" value - have you verified that it's definitely identical to the statement you are running in Mgmt Studio?  You could also debug the "RecordCount" property (of the "recset" variable) to confirm the actual number of records in that object

Comment: @Craig thank you for your comments....yes the SQL query is the same as what is in the VBA code and the parameters are exactly the same. The debug line is actually what I have copied and pasted into SSMS and above, so it's the exact same as what you can see above. How do you debug the "RecordCount" property?

Comment: recset.RecordCount will give you the number of rows that the recordset believe it contains.  That's at least a first step to confirm if the actual recordset is getting the total number of rows that you believe it should.  If it does - but you're then getting less output into the Excel sheet - then there'll be something not right about the "CopyFromRecordset" that you're doing

Comment: How are you actually checking the no of records returned?

Comment: thank you all for your comments in trying to resolve this - greatly appreciated! @Craig where do i put `recset.RecordCount` in order to get this? Sorry, I have never used this `recset.RecordCount` before so do not know how this works. @norie the SQL that gets printed in `debug.print SQLQry` i am copying & pasting into SSMS and this is where I can see the results disparity. @braX i use this template for a lot of other SQL/VBA queries and never had an issue before....I've change this to  `DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(1000000)` anyway to test but still having the same issue with only 145 results :(

Comment: Put a debug on the recset variable between the "Open" line and the "CopyFromRecordset" line

Comment: @Craig i get a record count of -1?

Comment: @PeterK Can I clarify? When you copy the SQL that's been created in VBA to SSMS and run it only 145 records are retuned?

Comment: @norie sure - when I copy & run into SSMS I have 1,481 records returned

Comment: Another "probably wont help" comment: In VBA, `.RecordCount` usually only returns a correct value after you move to the last record: `.MoveLast`

Comment: @braX, that is correct - my bad.  I was forgetting that the default cursor type for an ADO recordset is "forward only"

Comment: I'm not familiar with that SQL dialect at all but any chance this process retrieves multiple recordsets?

Comment: @PeterK, if you change your "recset.Open ..." line to be "recset.Open SQLQry, Conn, adOpenStatic" (just don't include the surrounding double-quotes), then you should get a value from the "recset.RecordCount" property

Comment: ...or do a `Movelast` and then get the count.

Comment: thank you everyone for helping me........i've tried `recset.Open SQLQry, Conn, adOpenStatic Debug.Print recset.RecordCount` but still comes as -1. if i do `recset.MoveLast Debug.Print recset.RecordCount` i get a `Rowset does not support fetching backward` error. should i do another stackoverflow question for this issue?

Comment: Long shot but check for `NextRecordset` - eg see `https://documentation.help/adosql/adoprg02_30tv.htm`

Comment: How many rows of data do you get in Excel if you stop the code immediately after Range("C17").CopyFromRecordset recset?

Comment: @norie i did try that to see if it was something to do with the vba after it somehow, but still only the 145 records appear if i stop it after `Range("C17").CopyFromRecordset recset` ...so frustrating as i know everything looks correct and using the debug!